# Pointer level return type based on template function arguments

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, variadic-templates, type-deduction

For a tensor class I would like to have a template creating functions like

```
double* mat(int size1);
double** mat(int size1, int size2);
double*** mat(int size1, int size2, int size3);
```

i.e. the pointer level of the return type depends on the number of inputs.
The base case would just be

```
double* mat(int size1){
  return new double[size1];
}
```

I thought a variadic template could somehow do the trick

```
template<typename T, typename... size_args>
T* mat(int size1, size_args... sizes) {
  T* m = new T[size1];
  for(int j = 0; j < size1; j++){
    m[j] = mat(sizes...);
  }
  return m;
}
```

Deducing the template parameter in `m[j] = mat(sizes...);` doesn't seem to work though when more than one recursive call would be necessary, as in

```
auto p = mat<double**>(2,3,4);
```

but how could I provide the parameter in the recursive call? The correct parameter would be one pointer level below `T`, that is `mat<double**>` for `T=double***`.
I feel like I miss something important about templates here.

Comment: If you allocate your tensor as one continuous block of memory with strides that determine how to navigate between dimensions, you can always return `double*`. You can also consider to add a wrapper class to manage the memory etc.

Comment: @wohlstad that is indeed what we're doing under the hood. Sadly the rest of the code relies on indexing of the form `m[i][j][k]`, so in those matrices we store the addresses of tensor elements. Far from ideal, I know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot declare `m` and return type as `T*` since it is not in multiple dimension.

```
template<typename T, typename size_type>
auto mat(size_type size){return new T[size];}

template<typename T, typename size_type, typename... size_types>
auto mat(size_type size, size_types... sizes){
    using inner_type = decltype(mat<T>(sizes...));
    inner_type* m = new inner_type[size];
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        m[j] = mat<T>(sizes...);
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. Using `using` and a `decltype` solves this in a very elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

For lack of a better name, I'm going to call the template meta-function that creates a pointer type with the desired "depth" and type, a "recursive pointer". Such a thing can be implemented like so:

```cpp
template <size_t N, class T>
struct RecursivePtr
{
    using type = RecursivePtr<N-1, T>::type*;
};

template <class T>
struct RecursivePtr<0, T>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <size_t N, class T>
using recursive_ptr_t = RecursivePtr<N, T>::type;
```

`recursive_ptr_t<4, int>` for example creates `int****`. So in your case you can go ahead and implement the `mat` function as:

```cpp
template <class... Args>
auto mat(Args... args)
{
    recursive_ptr_t<sizeof...(Args), double> m;
    
    // Runtime allocate your Npointer here.
    
    return m;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc922609879467d4)

Some ideas to give added type safety to the mat function are:

1. Add static asserts that all provided types are sizes
2. Statically assert that at least one size has been provided

Minor note, when I say runtime allocate your Npointer above, I mean something like:

```cpp
template <class T, class... Sz>
void alloc_ar(T* &ar, size_t s1, Sz... ss)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Sz))
    {
        ar = new T[s1];
        for (size_t i(0); i < s1; i++)
            alloc_ar(ar[i], ss...);
    }
    else
    {
        ar = new T[s1];
    }
}
```

Made a [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71c9ba6a307cd422) where I show the allocation, but not the deallocation.

A reasonable alternative to this is to allocate one contiguous chunk of memory (sized == multiplicate of dimensions) and use the multidimensional pointer to the beginning of that chunk for syntactic sugar when accessing it. This also provides an easier way to deallocate memory.

A second alternative is to use nested vector of vectors (of vectors of vectors...) with the same generation mechanics as the Npointer. This eliminates the need for manual memory management and would probably force you to wrap the whole thing in a more expressive class:

```cpp
template <class... Dims>
class mat
{
  template <size_t N, class T>
  struct RecursivePtr
  {
    using type = std::vector<RecursivePtr<N-1, T>::type>;
  };

  template <class T>
  struct RecursivePtr<0, T>
  {
    using type = T;
  };

  // This is the replacement to double***
  // translates to vector<vector<vector<double>>>
  RecursivePtr<N, T>::type _data; 

public:
  // construction, argument deduction etc ... 
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Your comments on the static asserts are super helpful. The idea of recursively deducing the type and the `using` that pointer type is great. This should be the same principle as the answer by @appleapple who uses a `decltype` instead of a recursive pointer class.